# Android : How to create oval size drawable resouce?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I am trying to create drawable resource oval com rectangle shape? I want exact the below shape
[image]

But I am getting the follow :

[image]

what I'm using:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle" >

  <gradient
    android:startColor="#36D53D"
    android:centerColor="#36D53D"
    android:endColor="#36D53D"
    android:angle="90"/>
  <padding android:left="3dp"
    android:top="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:bottom="5dp" />

  <corners android:radius="160dp"></corners>
</shape>
```

how to create the shape what I want? Thank you in advance

Comment: create a drawable shape which is a rectangle. Make it solid and provide a color, provide a size with corresponding width and height and lastly provide a corner that will control the radius per corner. Try to look at my answer I hope it will help you :)

Comment: you cannot do it in XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <solid android:color="#189B5F" />
      <corners
          android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
          android:topRightRadius="15dp"
          android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
          android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
          />
  </shape>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one for oval.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >

    <!-- fill/color -->
    <solid
        android:color="#ff0000"/>

    <!-- Control the width and height of the shape -->
    <size
        android:width="120dp"
        android:height="70dp"/>
</shape>
```

Rectangle with rounded corner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!-- fill/color -->
    <solid
        android:color="#ff0000"/>

    <!-- Control the width and height of the shape -->
    <size
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="70dp"/>

    <!-- Control the radius of each corners -->
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="30dp"
        android:topRightRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

use shape drawable and for android:shape give rectangle

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle">
</shape>
```

increase the corner dp value can keep checking. i think giving around 20-25dp for all corners will give you that shape. And for correction it is not oval it is rounded rectangle.

Comment: No Its not working. If I use shape=oval, I am getting full oval size

Comment: check modified answer